# How to capture a screenshot of other Android application without rooting device?

Tags: android, screenshot

For this I have searched a lot, but found nothing that suggests it is possible without rooting.

There is [android-screenshot-library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-screenshot-library/) but this requires native service to be started from PC on each device reboot ([UserGuide](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-screenshot-library/wikis/UserGuide.wiki)) and for normal user it might not be possible to do this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, you are welcome to use [the media projection APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) to collect a screenshot, with user approval.

Otherwise, no, this is not possible without rooting.